# mktextfm error with mathpazo

Tags: fonts, errors, mathpazo

I just set up a fresh TeXLive 2014 install on Linux, following the [Wikibooks minimal install guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installation) all the way through installing LaTeX. Now I'm trying to get the URW Palladio fonts working. I've installed the `mathpazo` package, and am trying to compile a simple test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error.

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm pplr7t
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation
    for pplr7t.
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pplr7t
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf pplr7t
! I can't find file `pplr7t'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pplr7t

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input pplr7t

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: pplr7t.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; 
    input pplr7t' failed to make pplr7t.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font OT1/ppl/m/n/10=pplr7t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

All of the documentation I've found suggests the pplr files are related to Palladio, and supplied by `mathpazo`, so I'm stumped. How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably you don't have the fonts. Try `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended` on terminal if you had installed TeXlive from terminal. Otherwise try `sudo su` and then `tlmgr --gui` to install that package.

Comment: That won't work for me because I'm running Arch. I should add that I didn't have this problem with TeXLive 2013.

Comment: So use `tlmgr` to install fonts package.

Comment: @cfr, but `tlmgr` will work, won't?

Comment: Note that those instructions are not a great guide if you have limited experience of installing and maintaining TeX. Far better to follow upstream's instructions and install the 'full' scheme. You are going to need to install a *lot* of additional stuff to get things working satisfactorily if you want to use packages such as `mathpazo`. It will be a pain. Unless you are short of disk space. go with upstream's defaults. Also, follow upstream's advice: don't install as root.

Comment: @Sigur Yes. But my comment crossed with yours so I didn't see yours until I'd posted mine.

Comment: @cfr Okay, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Follow either the quick install instructions or the full ones at http://www.tug.org/texlive/. What I did was created a special user and group (`texlive:texlive`) with permissions to write to `/usr/local/texlive` which I created ahead of the install. `texlive` is not in `sudoers`. I then logged in as `texlive` to install. This works well for me.

Comment: @cfr, ow. I always install TeXlive as root!

Comment: @Sigur Why? It is no more convenient to install as root and somewhat less secure. Why not follow upstream's recommendation? Things should be done as root only when necessary. I trust the people in charge of TeX Live but I believe they are human and therefore fallible. I like the fact that `tlmgr` ***cannot*** do `rm345 -rf /` (minus the typo) even if somebody screws up, hacks the server, whatever. It cannot touch my home directory either. It can *only* harm `/usr/local/texlive`. I see no reason to take entirely unnecessary risks. (If there was *any* benefit... but there is none.)

Comment: @cfr, well, I had never thought about those problems. Unfortunately I installed it 3 days ago (as root lol). I did that since when I tried to run `install-tl` as normal user we always got a warning with no permission to write on the target path.

Comment: @Sigur You can change the ownership of the directory if you want, though. Notice that every time you update, you run similar risks - especially when `tlmgr` itself is updated.

Comment: Is it possible to change the owner now or I have to install it again? Could you pass a link helping to create `texlive` user and how to update using it?

Comment: @cfr A medium install following the TeXLive install instructions didn't fix the problem. The space demands of a full install don't make it feasible for me. Hopefully someone knows what the underlying problem is.

Comment: @Sigur It should be possible to switch owners without reinstalling. At worst, if it didn't work you could reverse the command. (But I'm almost certain it would work.) I don't have a link but if you ask the question, I'll try to answer it. There are some differences between distros but I think they all have `useradd` even if there's a higher-level wrapper available as well.

Comment: @Sigur I thought maybe TL would provide instructions but all I can find is the note advising you not to install as root. It is not especially difficult to do, though. I wonder if there is an existing question where it would make sense to add this information?

Comment: @Nick The problem is that TeX is not finding the fonts. First, can you compile a minimal document without loading any packages? Just `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Testing\end{document}` for example? If so, what does `kpsewhich pplr7t.tfm` give? What does `kpsewhich mathpazo.sty` give?

Comment: @cfr A minimal document with no packages compiles fine. Running `kpsewhich pplr7t.tfm` doesn't give any output. Running `kpsewhich mathpazo.sty` returns `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120314/how-to-install-mathpazo-correctly-from-tex-live-manager), which provides an explanation and correct answer. The `mathpazo` package works after installing `fpl` and `palatino`.